# Changing vector layer dynamically using OpenLayers 4?

Tags: openlayers, geojson, vector

I need dynamically change vector layer on map, which is represented by some route in geojson. This new geojson I get from my service, so I have function changeRoute, which I will call in ajax on success :

```
function changeRoute(newRouteInGeoJSON) {
    // change vector layer here and redraw it by new Geojson...
}
```

And here is my actual code :

```
var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON({
featureProjection:"EPSG:3857"
});
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
features:format.readFeatures(routeJSON)
});

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'red',
            width: 4
        })
    })
});

var markersCooord = getMarkersCoordinates();


var sourceFeature = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform(markersCooord[0], 'EPSG:4326',
  'EPSG:3857'))
});

var targetFeature = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform(markersCooord[1], 'EPSG:4326',
  'EPSG:3857'))
});

var sourceSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: [sourceFeature] //add an array of features
});
var targetSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: [targetFeature] //add an array of features
});

var sourceStyle = new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Icon(({
    anchor: [0.5, 1],
    src: 'data/source.png'
  }))
});
var targetStyle = new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Icon(({
    anchor: [0.5, 1],
    src: 'data/target.png'
  }))
});

var sourceLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: sourceSource,
  style: sourceStyle
});
var targetLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: targetSource,
  style: targetStyle
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.XYZ({
                url: 'http://10.0.2.2:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/Bachelor%3Av_slovensko_group@EPSG%3A3857@png/{z}/{x}/{-y}.png'
            })
        }),
        vectorLayer,
        sourceLayer,
        targetLayer
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([22.00, 48.82]),
        minZoom: 10,
        maxZoom: 18,
        zoom: 10,
    }),
    controls: []
});
//var extent = source.getExtent();
//map.getView().fit(extent, map.getSize());

function getMarkersCoordinates() {
    var start, end;
    var isFirst = true;

    for (var i = 0; i < routeJSON.features.length; i++) {
        if (isFirst) {
            if (routeJSON.features[i].geometry != null) {
            start = routeJSON.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0];
            isFirst = false;
        }
        } else {
            if (routeJSON.features[i].geometry != null) {
                for (var j = 0; j < routeJSON.features[i].geometry.coordinates.length; j++)
                    end = routeJSON.features[i].geometry.coordinates[j];
                }
            }
        }
        return [start, end];
}
```

My current scripts using geojson to draw route, and calculate first and last coordinates to create geopoints for pins.

How do I use the function changeRoute to change my vector layer to new geojson?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just hold the vector layer you first added to the map and do the following

1. clear any existing features

   `vectorLayer.getSource().clear();`
2. Declare a new geojson format to parse the supplied route

   `var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON({
   featureProjection:"EPSG:3857"
   });`
3. Use the format to parse your new geojson and add the features to the source

   `vectorLayer.getSource().addFeatures(format.readFeatures(routeJSON))`

so propably your function should be something like:

```
function changeRoute(newRouteInGeoJSON) {
vectorLayer.getSource().clear();
var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON({
    featureProjection:"EPSG:3857"
    });
vectorLayer.getSource().addFeatures(format.readFeatures(newRouteInGeoJSON));
}
```

Comment: yep, works very well :)